# Can't find XDocument and XElement

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

I'm trying to parse an xml and I want to get access to either `XDocument` or `XElement`. Those 2 classes currently don't exist.

I'm using Visual Studio. Am I suppose to add a reference? I currently have System.Xml.linq selected but I still can't access the 2 classes above...

[image]

Comment: If you're targeting .NET 4.5.2, you shouldn't need to do anything else. Please give more details about your project type, and a [mcve] of the code you're trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `System.Xml.XDocument.dll` for `XDocument` and `XElement`.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.5.2):

[image]

If you don't have that dll on your system, 
you could install the [System.Xml.XDocument](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XDocument) NuGet package.

```
Install-Package System.Xml.XDocument -Version 4.3.0
```

PS: To read more how to install NuGet packages in Visual Studio, check [Quickstart: Install and use a package in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio)

Comment: If the OP is targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2, they shouldn't need to install a NuGet package.